# How to retrieve substrings using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to pull a few substrings out of a string that I don't have any control of. The string contains 3 pieces of information I need. They are:

```
Order #
Middle Digits
CV2 Number
```

Each of these pieces of information are a variable length. For example, in the string below, the order number is 2, but it could very well be 20 or 200, or 20174, or whatever. The middle digits could be 8 numbers or 2 numbers, etc. and the CV2 number could be 3, 2 or 1 number...

```
Here are the middle digits of the card number for order #2:

Middle Digits: 11111111

And here is the CV2 number:

CV2 Number: 444
```

In the above example string, I need to get the order number (2), the middle digits (11111111) and the CV2 number (444). These numbers have an arbitrary length or might not exist at all.

What PHP functions/logic can help me retrieve these values reliably? The only information I need are the numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: is there a certain format that you're going to be receiving these as?

Comment: The 4-line string above is the exact format I receive it in. The only part of the string that would ever be different are the actual numbers themselves.

Comment: Then you should be able to read line by line. Then for the second and fourth line take the substring past the ':' char plus maybe a ' '(space char) and return the following number

Comment: I see 3 good answers....hay all of them get downvote????

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into php's [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in conjunction with [PCRE regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for matching patterns of text.

PCRE regex syntax gives you a great deal of power for matching patterns. You could retrieve these numbers by implementing patterns like: (for order #NNNN), (Middle Digits: NNNN), (CV2 Number: NNNN) where NNNN would be the matched text.

**Edit**

For example, to match the order number, try something like:

```
preg_match('/order #([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
```

Then `$matches[1]` should contain the matched order number.

Comment: Yea, someone downvoted me too. I don't care though, they probably don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
The explode() function breaks a string into an array.
explode(separator,string,limit);
```

For ex :

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => world.
    [2] => It's
    [3] => a
    [4] => beautiful
    [5] => day.
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the length of the numbers though. They are of arbitrary length. I also can't rely on the preceding text to be a set length so I won't know the starting position for sure either. However, I can rely on the numbers following a certain format. For example, the order number will always follow the substring `order #` and the middle digits will always follow immediately after the substring `Middle Digits:`

Comment: So you should use explode function for this, just split the string and get the result.

Comment: Dead Man, I didn't downvote you if you were asking me. I upvoted you. Someone went through and downvoted all of us. SO should suspend people who do this... Thank you for your answer. All of these answers are good help.

Comment: Ya there was someone who downvoted everyone. They should be suspended

Answer (score -1):

You need 2 thinks to use:

1)substr() you can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)!

```
 string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

2)strpos() you can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)!

```
 int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

***haystack***-The string to search in.

***needle***-If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

***offset***-If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. Unlike strrpos() and strripos(), the offset cannot be negative.

You need to find the key word before the value you need like in `"CV2 Number: 444"` the key you need to look is position is `CV2 Number:` and the value you get by using substr() `444`

Or you can use Reg_exp in php using:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

while this example

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

will produce

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => def
            [1] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no clue why anyone would downvote you. I'll give this a try!